# Можно ли как-то указать путь на внешнюю библиотеку, которую я хочу использовать в проекте?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть возможность добавить зависимость или библиотеку в структуру проекта указавши к ней путь или добавить как модуль.

Но, что если я хочу просто указать путь к библиотеке которую я хочу использовать как путь... Так же как указан путь к `ndk` или `sdk` ведь эти папки не лежат в самом проекте, но мы их используем.

Таким образом я могу сослаться из нескольких проектов на одину и туже папку...

Я не хочу копировать файлы к себе в проект я хочу только ссылаться на какое то место на PC. Чтоб скажем если кто то редактирует какие то файлы то мне не нужно было делать пулл и все такое. У меня просто есть ссылка и то что сейчас там находиться то я и использую

Надеюсь у меня получилось обьяснить, что я хочу))

**EDIT**

Я имею ввиду такую возможность, есть скажем папка где то на PC в которой лежит 2 джава класса А и В . Добавляю (как то) путь в проект (как бы говорю вот там есть папка) и могу использовать эти файлы у себя в проекте. Вот такая идея...

Как сказал @woesss , что раньше в эклипсе была возможность добавлять линк на файл, это то что я ищу.

**EDIT**
Хочу попробовать способ описанный @woesss для теста я скачал как `zip` вот эту либу (так как нужен нормальный gradle-проект)

https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView

распаковал ее и указал к ней путь в `settings.gradle`

```
include ':app', ':library'

project(':library').projectDir = new File('C:/Users/tetavi/Downloads/Buffer/Lib_DELETE/CircularImageView-master/CircularImageView-master')
```

И так же указал в `gradle(module)`

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':library')
    ...
}
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку

```
Unable to find a matching configuration of project :library: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

**EDIT**

Вот градл файл из либы которую я пробую добавить

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
```

apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.40'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.1'
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

Comment: я могу предложить исходя из вашего комментария только использование библиотеки на гитхабе, то есть вы там сможете все что нужно менять, и оно будет обновляться автоматически

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko да, но я не хочу держать библиотеку на гитхабе, допустим библеотека у меня локально на PC...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно подключить модуль из другого проекта таким способом:
***settings.gradle:***

```
include ':app', ':library'
project(':library').projectDir = new File('path/to/library/project/libmodule')
```

***build.gradle(module):***

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':library')
    ...
}
```

Это проверенно работает, если библиотека - нормальный gradle-проект.
Но удобства в этом меньше, чем неприятных неожиданностей.
Библиотека правиться и пересобирается из любого проекта - кто-то что-то изменил и у всех посыпалось.

**P.S.** Хорошо, покажу на примере указанной либы с гитхаба:
Допустим я скачал её в зипе и распаковал в `C:\Users\woesss\dowloads\CircularImageView-master\`

***settings.gradle:***:

```
include ':app', ':library' // добавляем модуль ':library'
// указываем ему путь к папке нужного нам МОДУЛЯ в другом проекте
project(':library').projectDir = new File('C:\\Users\\woesss\\dowloads\\CircularImageView-master\\circularimageview')
```

***build.gradle(module):***

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    // добавляем только что подключенный модуль в зависимость
    implementation project(':library')
    ...
}
```

Это можно сделать и через меню, но только после удачной синхронизации.

Теперь модуль как бы в нашем проекте и требует от нас свои зависимости - смотрим конфиг её проекта и добавляем нужное в конфиг своего:

***build.gradle(project):***

```
// здесь импортируются константы из файла 'dependencies.gradle'
// значит его тоже нужно скопировать в свой проект
// или добавить содержимое, если он уже есть.
// Вот тут начинаются грабли, за которыми придётся следить
// - потому что там хранятся версии зависимостей
// и они не будут синхронизироваться без вашего участия)
apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'

// дальше добавляем то, чего ещё нет в нашем проекте
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.40'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.1'
    }
}
```

Всё - синхронизируемся, ребилдимся, работаем.

Comment: ваш вариант получше чем мой :) наверное ТС это и искал)

Comment: А почему есть возможность только добавлять библиотеку как "нормальный" gradle проект? Нет возможность добавить путь к папке и чтоб проект просто видел какие файлы там есть... Типо есть папка в ней 2 java класса A и В . Добавляю путь в проект и вижу эти классы и могу их использовать...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko а использовать [fileTree](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:fileTree(java.lang.Object)) вместо project что мешает ?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, тогда может проще сделать в проекте линк на эту папку. В Эклипсе, помню, при перетаскивании файлов мышью в проект предлагалось сделать линк вместо копии. В студии как-то не заметил такого функционала. Но можно сделать средствами ОС или продвинутых файл-менеджеров.

Comment: @woesss это то, что я имею ввиду! мне просто нужно указать линк я это описал в вопросе. Есть папка(где то) в ней 2 джава файла (А и В) я указываю линк на эту папку и исплозую в своем проекте классы А и В

Comment: Нет, вы имеете в виду указать путь к папке и включить её содержимое в сборку средствами IDE, но, кроме описанного в ответе, других вариантов я не знаю. Я же имею в виду [Символическую ссылку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: Хочу попробовать реализовать подход который вы предложили, но почему  то получаю ошибку. Добавил в вопрос... Есть предположиения?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то библиотеку не добавляем как модуль, верно? Просто указываем то, что написано у вас в ответе и все должно подключаться, так? Но у меня почему то при компиляции ошибка, типо нет подходящей конфигурации, хотя это полноценная либа с гитхаба, которая через зависимость подключается без проблем... Мне кажется вы, что то упустили в ответе...

Comment: Так мы подключаем модуль другого проекта к своему без копирования - чего студия через менюшки сделать не позволяет. В остальном он ничем не отличается и, соответственно, при сборке к нему применяется конфиг вашего проекта, а не того, в чьей папке он лежит. Поэтому все нужные ему зависимости и плагины, подключенные на уровне проекта теперь на вашей совести. Посмотрите в корне проекта библиотеки gradle-файлы - у вас есть, то что там?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос градл из либы. Попробуйте сделать у себя локально так как я описал в вопросе (это 5 минут дела) просто 1)создать новый проект 2)скачать эту либу https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView 3) Распаковать ее(так как она zip) в дерикторию не относящеюся к проекту 4) Сделать все то что вы написали в своем ответе (настройки градл). У вас работает? Я вроде все верно понял, да?

Comment: Скачал, подключил - убедился, разжевал как мог.

Comment: Да, это работает. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Можно например так сделать:

```
File > Project Structure > Dependencies Tab > Add module dependency
```

вот [доки](https://developer.android.com/studio/build) по этой теме. Я такое делал давненько, но у меня получилось, надеюсь и у вас все получится :)

Comment: Нет, это не совсем то что мне нужно, тем более этот подход я описал в вопросе... Я знаю, что можно добавить как модуль, но проблема в том, что студия копирует эти файлы в проект. И в итоге так или иначе ты используешь копиию ... Это означает, что если кто то поменяет файлы в изначальной дириктории, ты ничего про это не узнаешь... Так что это не совсем то что я спрашивал... Мой вопрос в другом